# Noise through speakers when ASUS RX 570 4GB is doing 3D operations

Tags: gpu, sound-card, noise

The noise is not coming from the case, it's coming through the speakers. It's inaudible when only browser, etc running. But when i start games, i hear a spinning up, higher pitched buzzing noise through system sound. It sounds like its frequency is connected to the GPU fan speed.

When i use the motherboards integrated soundcard this phenomena disappears, but i have quality external sound card (Scarlet i2i) and monitor speakers. So i rather use those then my headphones. Also all my PC components are quality.

I was reading some opinion that the Catalyst HDMI audio driver can interfere, but it's not installed.

Windows 10 64bit system.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: "I hear a spinning up, higher pitched buzzing noise through system sound." - Sounds like your fans causing Electromagnetic interference.  Verify you have proper grounding.  **This is unlikely a driver problem.**  Any additional information you might have, you believe will be helpful to answer your question, should be provided as an edit instead of a comment

Comment: @Ramhound if it's grounding problem, can it damage my system if i can't fix the grounding?

Comment: It will not damage your system, just your ears. And other EMI sensitive hardware.

Comment: @BarnaGyömörei - If it's a grounding problem, there is not specific safety issue, but you should still solve it.

Comment: For years, I have seen different hardware combinations create digital noise in the speakers. As far as I can remember I’ve never been able to solve that. It’s simply garbage hardware - specifically the audio hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had something similar a while back. I solved the interference with a ground loop isolator. Cheap to find online and will clear up some of that interference.